# Display error if search cannot be found in SQL?

Tags: php, html, sql, error-handling

To keep it simple, my search box searches for food within an external database.
The search works fine. If I search for pizza, the code finds pizza within the database and displays it. If I search for chicken, the code finds chicken. within the database etc.

```
<?php

$searchquery = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['searchquery'])); //this is how we search and display results 
$find_searchengine=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM searchengine WHERE food_name LIKE '%$searchquery%'"); //we look within the external database 
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($find_searchengine))


{
    $food_name = $row['food_name'];

    echo "$food_name<br / >";  //Sorry our servers are down today 

    }

?>
```

The problem is, my database of course does not contain all the foods in the world. So, if I did for search for lets say "Rice", nothing would come up, the page will not load anything, it wont change in any way whatsoever as if all  did was press the enter button.

Can anyone guide me in the right direction of how to display an error if a certain food cannot be found within the database.

Comment: As well as the answers below you may also want to look at converting to PDO and prepared statements your current code is deprecated and will be removed in future versions of PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   if(empty($row['food_name']))
    print"Food is not found":
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked perfectly.
Do you have any idea how to have the search word come up before the "Food is not found" sentence. 

So... lets say (Rice " is not found")

Comment: Send the entered word through url. Like header("location: page.php?word=".$enteredword)

Answer (score 3):

Just add a check if the query is getting any record. Try with -

```
if(mysql_num_rows($find_searchengine) > 0) {
     // process data
} else {
     //display error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($find_searchengine) > 0){
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($find_searchengine))
{
    $food_name = $row['food_name'];

    echo "$food_name<br / >";  //Sorry our servers are down today 

    }
}else{
      echo "not match found for search criteria";
}
```

NOTE: Above all these stop using mysql and start mysqli or pdo.